# jQuery to move alt text to each silbling element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried playing around with .append() .insertAdjacentHTML() and .insertAfter() to move each image's alt text to its sibling element, but it is not working as expected...

The target result is:
**Image 1**
Caption 1
**Image 2**
Caption 2

```js
var altText = $("img").attr("alt");
$("span#here").append(altText);
```

```css
.wrap {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.demo-img {
  width: 280px;
}
span#here {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4Y5jq?ver=ac72&q=90&m=6&h=201&w=358&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true" alt="Example Image Caption 1" class="demo-img">
  <span id="here"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://cdn-dynmedia-1.microsoft.com/is/image/microsoftcorp/gldn-M365-CP-Microsoft365-Commercial?wid=380&hei=213&fit=crop" alt="Example Image Caption 2" class="demo-img">
  <span id="here"></span>
</div>
```

Greatly appreciated it if anyone could help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one liner for this. You need to loop over the images and set the text in the loop

```js
$(".wrap img").each(function (_, img) {
  const alt = img.alt;
  $(img).next("span").text(alt);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4Y5jq?ver=ac72&q=90&m=6&h=201&w=358&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true" alt="Example Image Caption 1" class="demo-img">
  <span id="here"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://cdn-dynmedia-1.microsoft.com/is/image/microsoftcorp/gldn-M365-CP-Microsoft365-Commercial?wid=380&hei=213&fit=crop" alt="Example Image Caption 2" class="demo-img">
  <span id="here"></span>
</div>
```

Other way is to select the spans and reference the image

```js
$(".wrap span").text(function() {
  return $(this).prev('img').attr('alt');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://img-prod-cms-rt-microsoft-com.akamaized.net/cms/api/am/imageFileData/RE4Y5jq?ver=ac72&q=90&m=6&h=201&w=358&b=%23FFFFFFFF&l=f&o=t&aim=true" alt="Example Image Caption 1" class="demo-img">
  <span id="here"></span>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="https://cdn-dynmedia-1.microsoft.com/is/image/microsoftcorp/gldn-M365-CP-Microsoft365-Commercial?wid=380&hei=213&fit=crop" alt="Example Image Caption 2" class="demo-img">
  <span id="here"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks a lot for the excellent approach and clean solution!!!!